# include text and variable in ValidationError

Tags: django, django-models

I am using this code on the model to check if users are uploading images that are too large

code:

```
    def validate_image(image):
        file_size = image.file.size
        test = 'whoop'
        if file_size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
            raise ValidationError("image too large")
image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to=path_and_rename, validators=[validate_image])
```

however i want to include the name of the offending file if i use

```
raise ValidationError(image)
```

it displays the file name but if I try to include some text

```
raise ValidationError(image, "is too large")
```

it will only display whatever comes first either the variable or the string. How can i include both

[image]

Comment: `f'Image {image} is too large'`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string formatting to include the text of the image in a string, for example:

```
def validate_image(image):
    file_size = image.file.size
    if file_size > settings.MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE:
        raise ValidationError(f'Image {image} is too large')
```